# twitter bootstrap IE9, nav collapse not pushing rest of content down

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im not sure is this an issue with the content below it, or `nav-collapse` itself, But the only way I can seem to replicate the issue in firefox is by changing `float:left` to `float:none` in the code below. Basically when I toggle the menu the content below it doesnt get pushed down in IE9

```
.navbar .navbar-inner  .nav-collapse.collapse 
  {
    background: #6E2E8F;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    float: left;
    height: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar {overflow: visible;}
```

Here is the outputted html...

```
<div class="navbar">
<div class="navbar-inner">
   <a data-target=".nav-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="brand visible-phone">   Categories</a>
   <a data-target=".nav-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-navbar">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   </a>
<div class="nav-collapse collapse">
   <ul class="nav">
   <li>***CONTENT***</li>
    <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
     <span>Start Shopping
     </span><span class="active_downarrow"></span></a>
     <span class="sub-menu-response">
         <ul class="dropdown-menu" >  ***CONTENT***     </ul>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu" >  ***CONTENT***     </ul>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu" >  ***CONTENT***     </ul>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu" >  ***CONTENT***     </ul>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu" >  ***CONTENT***     </ul>
     </span>
     </li>
    <li>  ***CONTENT***  </li>
    <li> ***CONTENT***   </li>
    <li>***CONTENT*** </li>
   </ul>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the link to the site... http://bc_mobile.hailstormcommerce.com/

Comment: When the site is small enough to activate the collapsed menu it will be on a mobile or a tablet so is there really an issue here as I'm guessing you're resizing your desktop browser to see this issue?

Comment: I was thinking the same myself, but still, Im not sure how professional it is to not have it working at all, especially if you were demo-ing the responsive capabilities and the user was using Internet Explorer

Comment: Some of the Bootstrap examples with this functionality don't actually work correctly on my mobile. E.G. The jumbo carousel example doesn't push down the content when you open the collapsed menu. That's on my Nexus 4.

Comment: remove in height of the navigation/header; see this answer [#12897337][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12897337/twitter-bootstrap-push-content-when-top-navigation-its-opened-on-mobile-devic

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding this css class:

```
.nav-collapse.collapse.in {
height: auto !important;
}
```

Because when you drop-down the navigation, bootstrap gives it an initial width fixed.